# Generating an image then sending it without first saving it as a file?

Tags: php, image, file, base64

If I generate an image directly in a php script to be sent back to JS, is it mandatory to have this interoom step of saving the image to the file system ?

I create an image using imagecreate() then imagecopyresized() then want to send the result as base64 wrapped in json (Later I will want an array of strings rather than just one).

I couldn't find anything that base64_encode() would take in apart from the bytes from fread(). I find having to save to the file system wasteful and think there must be a better way!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to save the file at all. Simply use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$pngData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo base64_encode($pngData);
```

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add; There's a function `ob_get_clean()` which executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`